# Not connected to runtime

Tags: node.js

I am trying to debug my nodejs code in debug mode, but I am getting the following error in the debug console. Any idea?

[image]

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug content-service",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\app.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\src",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug test",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\node_modules\\lab\\bin\\lab",
            "args": [
                "--colors",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\test\\test.js"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\src",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        }
    ]
}
```

it works if I am not in debug mode.

Comment: Hmm... I had the same issue when I was not connected to the app process and seems you might not be doing so either. Have you checked your path? VScode is quite clean, that way.

Comment: I even put the path directly, but it does not work in debug mode,

Comment: I am not sure if you are in windows or Linux, and unsure of your path backslashes or slashes, nor sure of your workspace path structure. However, pls look at this video this is simple https://youtu.be/AX7uybwukkk Are you in VSCode or chrome native debugger or any other tool? Can you put a screenshot of the debugger tab not console

Comment: https://youtu.be/2oFKNL7vYV8

Comment: https://youtu.be/hfpkMyvSOp4

Comment: I don't see any problem in the .json file. Check out the videos may be it should be helpful. There is also a new debugger inbuilt in NodeJS now that starts v8 debugger with a node-debug command using node-inspector